# Profiling C# application without using external tools

Tags: c#, .net-core, profiling

I have a C# (dotnet core) application that gets input from the queue and processes it. The processing time is determined by many factors. One of them is the request itself.

My code looks something like this:

```
public static void main()
{
    DoWork(new TaskInformation("abc"));
}

public static void DoWork(TaskInformation input)
{
    InnerWork1(input);
    InnerWork2(input);
}

private static void InnerWork1(TaskInformation input)
{
    // Running code here.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

private static void InnerWork2(TaskInformation input)
{
    // Running code here.
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

In order to improve the performance of my application, I want to develop a small tool that will run and mesure execution time. If the time is above some threshold - it will do something.

So, what I want to do is "wrap" my inner functions (`InnerWork1\2`) with `Stopwatch` automatically - without doing it programmatically.

The way I'll turn on this profiling feature should be something like:

```
public static void main()
{
    RunWithProfiling(DoWork, new TaskInformation("abc"));
}
```

So, in this case the expected profiling result will be:

```
DoWork - took 3 seconds
    InnerWork1 - took 1 second
    InnerWork2 - took 2 second
```

### Questions:

1. The question is if it possible to implement a mechanism like this? Maybe with reflection?
2. Is this possible to run a C# profiler from code? Something like "the code will profile itself".

Comment: Look into BenchmarkDotNet: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegate to pass your method to a `RunWithProfiling` method, in my example I will use `Action`, then measure its invoke time with `Stopwatch`:

```
private static void RunWithProfiling(Action method)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    method.Invoke();
    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"{method.Method.Name} - took {stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds} second(s).");

}
```

and usage

```
public static void DoWork()
{
    RunWithProfiling(InnerWork1);
    RunWithProfiling(InnerWork2);
}
```

You can for example return `long` with `RunWithProfiling` method, then sum results up to get whole execution time.